# C trying to find \r\n\r\n in headers

Tags: c, windows

I am trying to find the last occurrence of `\r\n\r\n` and delete everything before it (and including it). I am creating a socket and downloading a file, the file then would get saved. The HTTP headers get saved in the file (and according to the hex editor `\r\n\r\n` does exist). But I can't seem to find it using `strstr`, according to MSDN `recv` returns char so it should be able to find it?

```
    while ((tmpres = recv(sock, buf, BUFSIZ, 0)) > 0)
    {
char *p = strstr(buf, "\r\n\r\n");
printf("%s", p);
exit(1);
        if (fwrite(buf, 1, tmpres, fp) != tmpres) {
            printf("Error writing buffer");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
```

Yet the strstr returns null?

[image: hex codes]

It clearly writes 0D0A0D0A to the file, so I am unsure of what is going on.

Comment: why dont just print `buf` (I would just print each char in hex/ascii so it is like your hex editor view) and confirm it actually contain the chars as you expect. if not run it through a debugger and examine `buf` content.

Comment: Is the dump you pasted from your program or from some other source. can you print `buf` as I mentioned above and check whether you see 0D0A0D0A there.

Comment: can you add this before `strstr()` call and check whether you see a 0D0A0D0A `    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(buf); i++)
        printf("%02X", buf[i]);
`

Comment: `    char buf[] = "hello world\r\n\r\nMZ";
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(buf); i++)
        printf("%02X", buf[i]);
    char *p = strstr(buf, "\r\n\r\n");
    printf("%s", p);`
this works fine for me, prints `68656C6C6F20776F726C640D0A0D0A4D5A

MZ
`

Comment: That's weird... it doesn't have a `0D0A0D0A` only a bunch of single `0D0A` then the last header (which is `X-Amz-Cf-Id: random string`) then it goes into a bunch of `FCCCCCCC` which I assume is the actual data.

Comment: If I do a `curl -i` on the site it returns `\r\n\r\n` and `\r\n\r\n` gets written to the file (exactly where it should be).

Comment: If I do a different site it works fine. I was using `http://download.piriform.com/ccsetup407.exe`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41161/discussion-between-dpp-and-steven)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to handle the fact that the end of header marker might appear across multiple `recv` calls. It is reasonably plausible that the server sends the headers, each terminated by `\r\n` and then `send`s the body of the request prefixed with `\r\n` to signal the end of the headers and start of the "body" resulting in the sequence `\r\n\r\n` being split across `recv` calls.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, the wonders of text files and standard I/O.

When you open a file in text mode, the native line endings are changed so that what the program sees is just `\n` as the line ending, even if what is on disk is different.

To see the `\r\n` line endings, you'd have to open the file in binary mode.

> ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §7.21.2 **Streams**
>
> ¶2 A text stream is an ordered sequence of characters composed into lines, each line
> consisting of zero or more characters plus a terminating new-line character. Whether the
> last line requires a terminating new-line character is implementation-defined. Characters
> may have to be added, altered, or deleted on input and output to conform to differing
> conventions for representing text in the host environment. Thus, there need not be a oneto-
> one correspondence between the characters in a stream and those in the external
> representation. Data read in from a text stream will necessarily compare equal to the data
> that were earlier written out to that stream only if: the data consist only of printing
> characters and the control characters horizontal tab and new-line; no new-line character is
> immediately preceded by space characters; and the last character is a new-line character.
> Whether space characters that are written out immediately before a new-line character
> appear when read in is implementation-defined.

Comment: I'm not sure that is applicable to me, that is correct but the data (`buf`) is coming from a socket (site.com) not from a file. Anyways I opened the file I write too in `wb` mode anyways.